# Is using exFat (linux driver) for writing backups safe?

Tags: partitioning, backup, ext4, clonezilla, exfat

Using an exFat partition gives me the advantage to be able to read and write on Windows and Mac natively.

While Windows and Mac are using the original driver from Microsoft (Apple bought a license), the Linux driver is reverse engineered.

So my question is: How safe is the exFat Linux driver for writing backups?
Is it a dumb idea? May I expect a read / write error? Would ext4 be more safe?

I'm using Clonezilla btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use the same setup here at my workplace, CloneZilla to a USB or Windows shared file server. Works fine to ExFAT with no memorable errors.